# How do I check the component type of values inside the $slots?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'll provide a simple example that would demonstrate the problem I'm facing.

So I have a page that includes the following code:

```js
<Slider>
  <Slide>
    <p>test 1</p>
  </Slide>
  <Slide> test 2 </Slide>
  <div>test3</div>
</Slider>
```

The problem is within the mounted section of the Slider.

Inside Slider

```js
<template>
  <div class="h-48 w-full">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    slides: [],
  }),
  watch: {
    slides() {
      console.log(this.slides);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$slots.default().forEach((vNode) => {
      console.log(vNode);
      // this.slides.push(node.componentInstance)
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

**How do I check if the vNode is an instance of the Slide component?**
The console log return the following object:

```js
{
    "__v_isVNode": true,
    "__v_skip": true,
    "type": {
        "__hmrId": "6e03689e",
        "__file": "<route to project>/src/components/CarouselSlide.vue"
    },
    "props": null,
    "key": null,
    "ref": null,
    "scopeId": null,
    "slotScopeIds": null,
    "children": {
        "_": 1
    },
    "component": null,
    "suspense": null,
    "ssContent": null,
    "ssFallback": null,
    "dirs": null,
    "transition": null,
    "el": null,
    "anchor": null,
    "target": null,
    "targetAnchor": null,
    "staticCount": 0,
    "shapeFlag": 36,
    "patchFlag": 0,
    "dynamicProps": null,
    "dynamicChildren": null,
    "appContext": null
}
```

Slide is just the following:

```js
<template>
  <div class="slide">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

Here is a demo: [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. `type` is supposed to be equal to `Slide` component

Comment: I added now a demo @EstusFlask

Comment: I see. What I wrote above is applicable to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to React element objects represented by JSX, Vue vnode objects have `type` property that is a string for DOM elements, and a component for Vue components.

There should be a check:

```
if (vNode.type === Slide) ...
```